# Python: suggestions to improve a chunk-by-chunk code to read several millions of points

Tags: python, performance, coding-style, matplotlib, chunked-encoding

I wrote a code to read `*.las` file in Python. `*las` file are special ascii file where each line is `x,y,z` value of points.

My function read `N`. number of points and check if they are inside a polygon with `points_inside_poly`.

I have the following questions:

1. When I arrive at the end of the file I get this message: `LASException: LASError in "LASReader_GetPointAt": point subscript out of range` because the number of points is under the chunk dimension. I cannot figure how to resolve this problem.
2. `a = [file_out.write(c[m]) for m in xrange(len(c))]` I use `a =` in order to avoid video print. Is it correct?
3. In `c = [chunk[l] for l in index]` I create a new list `c` because I am not sure that replacing a new chunk is the smart solution (ex: `chunk = [chunk[l] for l in index]`).
4. In a statement `if else...else` I use `pass`. Is this the right choice?

Really thank for help. It's important to improve listen suggestions from expertise!!!!

```
import shapefile
import numpy
import numpy as np
from numpy import nonzero
from liblas import file as lasfile
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from matplotlib.nxutils import points_inside_poly  


# open shapefile (polygon)
sf = shapefile.Reader(poly)
shapes = sf.shapes()
# extract vertices
verts = np.array(shapes[0].points,float)

# open las file
f = lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r') # open LAS
# read "header"
h = f.header

# create a file where store the points
file_out = lasfile.File(outFile,mode='w',header= h)


chunkSize = 100000
for i in xrange(0,len(f), chunkSize):
    chunk = f[i:i+chunkSize]

    x,y = [],[]

    # extraxt x and y value for each points
    for p in xrange(len(chunk)):
        x.append(chunk[p].x)
        y.append(chunk[p].y)

    # zip all points 
    points = np.array(zip(x,y))
    # create an index where are present the points inside the polygon
    index = nonzero(points_inside_poly(points, verts))[0]

    # if index is not empty do this otherwise "pass"
    if len(index) != 0:
        c = [chunk[l] for l in index] #Is It correct to create a new list or i can replace chunck?
        # save points
        a = [file_out.write(c[m]) for m in xrange(len(c))] #use a = in order to avoid video print. Is it correct?
    else:
        pass #Is It correct to use pass?

f.close()
file_out.close()
```

code proposed by @Roland Smith and changed by Gianni

```
f = lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r') # open LAS
h = f.header
# change the software id to libLAS
h.software_id = "Gianni"
file_out = lasfile.File(outFile,mode='w',header= h)
f.close()
sf = shapefile.Reader(poly) #open shpfile
shapes = sf.shapes()
for i in xrange(len(shapes)):
    verts = np.array(shapes[i].points,float)
    inside_points = [p for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r') if pnpoly(p.x, p.y, verts)]
    for p in inside_points:
        file_out.write(p)
f.close()
file_out.close()
```

i used these solution:
1) reading **f = lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r')** and after the read **head** because i need in the *.las output file
2) close the file 
3) i used **inside_points = [p for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r') if pnpoly(p.x, p.y, verts)]** instead of

```
with lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r') as f:
...     inside_points = [p for p in f if pnpoly(p.x, p.y, verts)]
...
```

because i always get this error message

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: _*exit*_**

Comment: to avoid `AttributeError: __exit__` you could use `contextlib.closing()` e.g.: `with closing(lasfile.File(..)) as f: ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding (1):

First, why are you using chunks? Just use the lasfile as an iterator (as shown in the [tutorial](http://www.liblas.org/tutorial/python.html)), and process the points one at a time. The following should get write all the points inside the polygon to the output file, by using the [`pnpoly`](http://matplotlib.org/api/nxutils_api.html) function in a list comprehension instead of `points_inside_poly`.

```
from liblas import file as lasfile
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.nxutils import pnpoly

with lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r') as f:
    inside_points = (p for p in f if pnpoly(p.x, p.y, verts))
    with lasfile.File(outFile,mode='w',header= h) as file_out:
        for p in inside_points:
            file_out.write(p)
```

The five lines directly above should replace the whole big `for`-loop. Let's go over them one-by-one:

- `with lasfile.File(inFile`...: Using this construction means that the file will be closed automatically when the `with` block finishes.
- Now comes the good part, the generator expression that does all the work (the part between `()`). It iterates over the input file (`for p in f`). Every point that is inside the polygon (`if pnpoly(p.x, p.y, verts)`) is added to the generator.
- We use another `with` block for the output file
- and all the points (`for p in inside_points`, this is were the generator is used)
- are written to the output file (`file_out.write(p)`)

Because this method only adds the points that are inside the polygon to the list, you don't waste memory on points that you don't need!

You should *only* use chunks if the method shown above doesn't work. 
When using chunks you should handle the exception properly. E.g:

```
from liblas import LASException

chunkSize = 100000
for i in xrange(0,len(f), chunkSize):
    try:
        chunk = f[i:i+chunkSize]
    except LASException:
        rem = len(f)-i
        chunk = f[i:i+rem]
```

Regarding (2): Sorry, but I fail to understand what you are trying to accomplish here. What do you mean by "video print"?

Regarding (3): since you are not using the original chunk anymore, you can re-use the name. Realize that in python a "variable" is just a [nametag](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names).

Regarding (4): you aren't using the `else`, so leave it out completely.

Comment: Thanks Ronald,

"why are you using chunks?"
I am trying to use chunk instead of line-by-line for two reasons:
1) points_inside_poly(points, verts) work with more than one points
2) i have more than 200 milion of points and reading line-by-line (= points-by-points) it's really slow

Comment: Dear Ronald, 
i didn't get your suggestion about "except LASException:". Please, Could you help me to understand?

thanks gianni

Comment: using the try: except LASException: there is the following message 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'LASException' is not defined

Comment: Yeah, the exception should be imported as well, otherwise it won't be known. The reason for using the `try/except` is to catch and handle the situation where the indexing of `f` would fail and trigger the exception. Concerning speed, using the list comprehension (which is _not_ reading line-by-line) should be a lot faster than a `for`-loop, if your machine has sufficient memory.

Comment: Dear Roland, 

thanks for your help and your time. I am pretty quite new in python but i wish to learn. I don't like abuse of the free time of people, but i wish to ask these pleasures:

1) I understand you are really able and from skill people we can learn. Could me show your solution (just the first lines)? Thanks

2) could me show how i can import LASException? I am honest to say i triyed a lot of time today. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer, making it even shorter. The so-called "list comprehension" to the right of `inside_points` in the first code sample is the crucial bit.

Comment: Hey Roland Thanks, really thanks. I will post my final code in the end with some note. But please could you ri-write again the list compression method to read only x and y that you posted two days ago? With list compression  you open me a World!!! thanks

Comment: genexpr might save memory compared to the list comprehension. Why do you create a whole list at once if you need only one element at a time? Just replace `[]` with `()` in the `inside_points` definition.

Comment: hey Roland thanks alwyas. You help is great the only problem is:
from liblas import LASException because i have this message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name LASException

Comment: Try `from liblas.core import LASException`