# Problems with islice to read N number of lines at a time

Tags: python, performance, chunks

I am trying to use "from itertools import islice" in order to read a number of lines at a time from a *.las file using the liblas module. (my goal is reading chunk-bychunk)

following the question: [Python how to read N number of lines at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335839/python-how-to-read-n-number-of-lines-at-a-time)

> islice() can be used to get the next n items of an iterator. Thus,
>   list(islice(f, n)) will return a list of the next n lines of the file
>   f. Using this inside a loop will give you the file in chunks of n
>   lines. At the end of the file, the list might be shorter, and finally
>   the call will return an empty list.

I used the the following code:

```
from numpy import nonzero
from liblas import file as lasfile
from itertools import islice


chunkSize = 1000000

f = lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r') # open LAS
while True:
    chunk = list(islice(f,chunkSize))
    if not chunk:
        break
    # do other stuff
```

but i have this problem:

```
len(f)
2866390

chunk = list(islice(f, 1000000))
len(chunk)
**1000000**
chunk = list(islice(f, 1000000))
len(chunk)
**1000000**
chunk = list(islice(f, 1000000))
len(chunk)
**866390**
chunk = list(islice(f, 1000000))
len(chunk)
**1000000**
```

when the file f arrives in the end the islice restart to read the file.

Thanks for any suggestions and help. It's very appreciate

Comment: Gah, so your `lasfile.File` type is breaking all iterator conventions?!

Comment: i have really a bad moments with lasfile.File

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible; this appears to be idiosyncratic behaviour concerning an unpopular library `liblas`, and should be considered a bug in that library.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it would be easy enough to write a generator to yield n lines at a time:

```
def n_line_iterator(fobj,n):
    if n < 1:
       raise ValueError("Must supply a positive number of lines to read")

    out = []
    num = 0
    for line in fobj:
       if num == n:
          yield out  #yield 1 chunk
          num = 0
          out = []
       out.append(line)
       num += 1
    yield out  #need to yield the rest of the lines
```

Comment: Thanks but in "if num = n:" there is a problem 

  File "<module2>", line 16
    if num = n:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Gianni -- Sorry, I was out of town for a week and apparently forgot how to code.  That was an error.  I've already updated and fixed that one.  Let me know if you find any more.

Comment: no problem and thanks!!! I have really bad moments with libals module. I can not read in chunks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769353/python-suggestions-to-improve-a-chunk-by-chunk-code-to-read-several-millions-of

it's two days i am trying :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused -- Does the updated code I posted fail in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Change the sourcecode of `file.py` that belongs to the liblas package. Currently `__iter__` is defined as ([src on github](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/blob/master/python/liblas/file.py#L316))

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Iterator support (read mode only)

      >>> points = []
      >>> for i in f:
      ...   points.append(i)
      ...   print i # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
      <liblas.point.Point object at ...>
    """
    if self.mode == 0:
        self.at_end = False
        p = core.las.LASReader_GetNextPoint(self.handle)
        while p and not self.at_end:
            yield point.Point(handle=p, copy=True)
            p = core.las.LASReader_GetNextPoint(self.handle)
            if not p:
                self.at_end = True
        else:
            self.close()
            self.open()
```

You see that when file is at end it is closed and opened again, so iteration starts again at the beginning of the file.

Try to remove the last `else` block after the while, so the right code for the method should be:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Iterator support (read mode only)

      >>> points = []
      >>> for i in f:
      ...   points.append(i)
      ...   print i # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
      <liblas.point.Point object at ...>
    """
    if self.mode == 0:
        self.at_end = False
        p = core.las.LASReader_GetNextPoint(self.handle)
        while p and not self.at_end:
            yield point.Point(handle=p, copy=True)
            p = core.las.LASReader_GetNextPoint(self.handle)
            if not p:
                self.at_end = True
```

Comment: Thanks halex,
i have really bad moments with liblas. yesterday and today I am trying to read in chunck but lasfile.File type is breaking all iterator conventions. I am following all exemples in google but always there is a new problem.

see please:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769353/python-suggestions-to-improve-a-chunk-by-chunk-code-to-read-several-millions-of

Comment: This is a very interesting design.  However, you should be able to exhaust the iterator, I still don't understand why it loops around rather than requiring a new loop to restart it...

Comment: they create libals module in order to read *.las file in Python. *.las file is a special format to store "laser data" called LiDAR http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIDAR. The las file is a  ASPRS LIDAR data exchange format where ASPRS is the American Society of Photogrammetry and Remote Sensing

Comment: example: yesterday i tried 
for i in xrange(0,len(f), chunkSize):
chunk = f[i:i+chunkSize]
the normal way i use to read text file in chunk but nothing. When arrive in the end of the file i get a message error