# Reading all lines in a file with list comprehension

Tags: python, file-io, list-comprehension

I have a simple question and sorry if i post in stackoverflow. I am quite new in python and i don't remember how i can read in list compression a x,y,z

my file is a x,y,z file where each line is a points:

```
x1,y1,z1
x2,y2,z2
x3,y3,z3
........

inFile = "Myfile.las"

with lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r') as f:
     # missing part
     points =[]
```

what i wish to save an object with only x and y

Thanks in advance and sorry for the simple question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You you wanted a list of x and y coordinates, it's easy enough:

```
with lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r') as f:
     # missing part
     points = [line.split(',')[:2] for line in lasfile]
```

If these coordinates are integers, you can convert them to python int (from str) with a quick call to `map()`:

```
points = [map(int, line.split(',')[:2]) for line in lasfile]
```

In python 3, where `map` is a generator, it's probably best to use a nested list comprehension:

```
points = [[int(i) for i in line.split(',')[:2]] for line in lasfile]
```

This'll result in a list of lists:

```
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]
```

Comment: Or a list of iterables in python3.x :-/ -- Sometimes I wish they had kept a map-like function which returns a list.  `lmap` or something ...

Comment: @mgilson: Indeed; in which case a nested list comprehension would probably be the more readable.

Comment: thanks my idea is reading the x and y and find Xmax, Xmin, Ymax and Ymin. I wrote a code but is really not elegant.

Comment: using your code i have this problem 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: @Gianni: `lasfile.File` is not a context manager then and cannot be used in a `with` statement; this has nothing to do with my code, your question also uses `with`.

Comment: yes true. Yesterday
with lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r') as f:
...     inside_points = [p for p in f if pnpoly(p.x, p.y, verts)]
...

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769353/python-suggestions-to-improve-a-chunk-by-chunk-code-to-read-several-millions-of

was working and today no. I cannot explain what's happend

Comment: @Gianni: From what I can see from your questions, `lasfile.File()` is breaking all *sorts* of python conventions..

Comment: @Gianni: glancing over that [project's codebase](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/blob/master/python/liblas/file.py) I see no support for using `File` objects as context managers *at all*. You *always* should get an attribute error on `__exit__`.

Comment: Hey Martijin i resolved like this:
f = lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r')  
points = [(p.x,p.y) for p in f]
X_Max = max(zip(*points)[0])
X_Min = min(zip(*points)[0])
Y_Max = max(zip(*points)[1])
Y_Min = min(zip(*points)[1])

in order to get the X min and max and the Y min and max

Comment: @Gianni: Please don't edit my answer; your problem was with how to do the list comprehension, not how to handle your file object.

Comment: @PoweRoy: That edit should have been rejected, not 'improved'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  really sorry i am new of stackover. First and last time i do. Sorry again

Comment: @MartijnPieters: sorry missed that someone else made the addition. Thought it was the one who posted.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Edits to your own posts *never* need approval. *All* edits in the review queue are by someone editing a post that is not their own.